# Octonions, Invariance of domain and the Fundamental theorem of algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, algebraic-topology, linear-transformations, clifford-algebras

The following theorem is a corollary of the topological invariance of domain:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R^n}$ be a continuous and injective function. If $|f(x)|\rightarrow \infty$ as $|x|\rightarrow \infty$, then $f$ is surjective.

As I understand, every octonion $q \in \mathbb{O}$ can be represented as a matrix that has an inverse. Thus, every octonion polynomial $p(q)$ is a non-singular linear map from $\mathbb{R^8}$ to $\mathbb{R^8}$. If it holds that $|p(q)|\rightarrow \infty$ as $|q|\rightarrow \infty$, then can we infer from the above theorem that $0\in p(\mathbb{O})$ ?

Comment: It's not very clear what $p$ is in your question. Is it a polynomial $p\in \mathbb{R}[X]$? So do you mean that $p(q)\in \mathbb{H}$?

Comment: @CaptainLama Here $p(q)$ for all $q \in \mathbb{O}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{O}$.

Comment: You will have to explain what you mean by that. What kind of subset? And if this is the case, then $p(\mathbb{O})$ does not make sense.

Comment: @CaptainLama I made a correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are confusing the fact that $p(q)$ can be interpreted as a bijective linear map $\mathbb{R}^8\to \mathbb{R}^8$, and the fact that $p:\mathbb{O}\to \mathbb{O}$ is injective.

To apply the theorem you quote, you would need $p$ to be injective, but it is not the case at all (it will usually have infinite fibers).

Comment: Apparently this was a blunder :)